# Fragment, DialogFragment or Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I've a scenario that I want to achieve and I have no idea how to do it: what I want is when the user click on the FAB a window appears (with animation from right to left) within the details of the chosen product. I think about several solutions like adding (not replacing) a fragment on my existing fragment (a fragment contains the list of products) :

I get the context in the constructor :

```
 public ProductListAdapter(Context context, List<ProductPojo> productPojoList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.productPojoList = productPojoList;
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        try {
            activity = (AppCompatActivity) context;
        }catch (ClassCastException e){
            Utils.myLogMsgs("can't get the frag manager with this");
        }

    }
```

and than in my onBindViewHolder I manage the click event :

```
productHolder.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ProductDetailsFragment productDetailsFragment = new ProductDetailsFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.product_animation_enter, R.anim.product_animation_exit);
                    transaction.add(R.id.item_detail_container, productDetailsFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            });
```

unfortunately it's not working, nothing happens when I click the fab!!
I've been thinking about implementing a navigation drawer to achieve the behaviour but I don't know if it's a solution ?!

this is my logcat when I press the fab :

```
09-01 13:29:12.332 14826-14826/com.hermesit.bsproject I/Choreographer: Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-01 13:29:13.072 14826-14826/com.hermesit.bsproject D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1354K, 20% free 7623K/9460K, paused 37ms, total 38ms
09-01 13:29:13.772 14826-14826/com.hermesit.bsproject I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-01 13:29:24.212 394-452/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.212 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process E/SoundPool: error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
09-01 13:29:24.222 394-452/system_process W/AudioService: onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
09-01 13:32:30.922 394-445/system_process D/MobileDataStateTracker: default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
09-01 13:33:33.732 394-445/system_process D/ConnectivityService: Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
09-01 13:33:33.812 394-445/system_process D/ConnectivityService: Done.
09-01 13:33:33.812 394-445/system_process D/ConnectivityService: Setting timer for 720seconds
```

what I have is this :
[find image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN8mI.jpg)

and what I want is this : 
[find image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNf4D.jpg)

PS : My target device is a tablet 7" or 10" running on Android 4.4 kikat api 19.

Comment: Fragments are probably the best option here. Do you get any errors or messages in the Logcat when clicking the fab? Make sure to post logs

Comment: Write here LOG message when fab is clicked!

Comment: Thanks @Timmo for your reply, I added my logcat when I click the plus button, the problem is that the fragment doesn't appear !

Comment: Thanks @Zafar for your reply I edit my answer by adding the logcat